# Spark streaming job doesn't delete shuffle files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that run on EMR, read messages from Kafka and output to S3.

I use emr-5.17.0, i.e hadoop 2.8.4, spark 2.3.1

The problem is that shuffle files are being accumulated in: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1540126328960_0001/

and never get deleted until I run out of space on disk

The files looks like: shuffle_328_127_0.index, shuffle_328_134_0.data

I did try to update Yarn's policy like so:
yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms    300000
yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb         5000

But it did not solve the problem.

Currently I restart the job automatically and start a new one every few hours and when the application is stopped it deletes the cache

What can I do in order to make yarn delete the cache files?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem by configuration alone? I have a similar issue, but I don't want to run crons or anything like that.

Comment: @Interfector did you fine anything?

Comment: Sorry, cannot remember the exact context or if I had indeed found a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had a cron job (hourly) clean up the files/directories older than 6 hours to fix the disk out of space issue, i did not find a parameter in spark/yarn that would do this automatically, here are the details.

crontab entry.

```
0 * * * * /home/hadoop/clean_appcache.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

clean_appcache.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_LOC=/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache
sudo find $BASE_LOC/ -mmin +360 -exec rmdir {} \;
sudo find $BASE_LOC/ -mmin +360 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable dynamic allocation. Executors are killed before doing all the cleanup. If the executors are not constantly killed/created the leak is gone.

To do that, in your spark-submit command:

```
  --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are not shuffle files, those are cached files of RDDs or Dataframes.

Yarn only deletes cache files if your application dies, so it's really what you're trying to do with those cached files.
Maybe try unpersist once you're done with those cache files.